# LEFT JOIN and IS NULL in nested CONCAT returning NULL only

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, group-concat

Each student has multiple time period to pay fee, I want to fetch fee time period in which fee hasn't payed, or in `MySQL` language - fetch row which is not in another table.

Here, I am using nested `GROUP_CONCAT` in `MySQL`, and `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL`

Table `student` - lists of student

```
id  |   ttl     |   cls |   sec
===============================
1   |   Rohit   |   1   |   1
2   |   Karuna  |   2   |   0
```

Table `cls` - lists of Class

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   One
2   |   Two
```

Table `sec` - lists of section

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   A
2   |   B
```

Table `fee_tm` - lists of Fee time Period

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   Jan
2   |   Feb
```

Table `std_fee` - lists of Fee period assigned to Student

```
id  |   s_id|   f_id|   fee|    f_tm    
====================================
1   |   1   |   4   |   100|    1
```

According to tables structure and row in table, I am **expecting** following output with my MySQL code.

```
//(student.id-student.cls-student.sec-student rest of the fee.time(Month1,Month2..))

1-Rohit-One-A-Feb,
2-Karuna-Two-John,Feb
```

but what I get (I wanna apply `NULL` and `LEFT JOIN` only for **fee time**, so remaining **fee time** can be fetched, but here it is apply to whole result)

```
2-Karuna-Two-
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d28199/4)

**MySQL Code**

```
  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(student.id,'-',student.ttl,'-',cls.ttl,'-',
          COALESCE(sec.ttl,''),
          COALESCE(CONCAT('-',fee_tm.ttl),'')) 
    ORDER BY student.id) AS stdt
  FROM
    student
  JOIN
    cls ON cls.id=student.cls
  LEFT JOIN
    sec ON sec.id=student.sec
  LEFT JOIN
    std_fee ON std_fee.s_id = student.id
  LEFT JOIN
    fee_tm ON fee_tm.id = std_fee.f_tm
  WHERE
    std_fee.f_tm IS NUll
```

Comment: Try moving `WHERE std_fee.f_tm IS NULL` to the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write a subquery for `std_fee` and `fee_tm` tables and let `std_fee.f_tm IS NUll` condition in `ON` to make a result set.

> What's the difference let the condition between putting in `where` and `ON`?

You are using `OUTER JOIN` if you don't put conditions in `ON` you will miss row data by this `std_fee.f_tm IS NUll` condition, because you match in `fee_tm.id = std_fee.f_tm`

query looks like this.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(student.id,'-',student.ttl,'-',cls.ttl,'-',
          COALESCE(sec.ttl,''),
          COALESCE(CONCAT(t1.ttl),'')) 
    ORDER BY student.id) AS stdt
  FROM
    student
  JOIN
    cls ON cls.id=student.cls
  LEFT JOIN
    sec ON sec.id=student.sec
   LEFT JOIN
   (
      select s.id,GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(fee_tm.ttl,'')) ttl
      FROM
          student s
      LEFT JOIN
          std_fee ON std_fee.s_id = s.id
      LEFT JOIN
          fee_tm ON fee_tm.id = std_fee.f_tm  or std_fee.f_tm IS NUll
      GROUP BY s.id
   ) t1 on t1.id = student.id
   group by student.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d28199/48/0)**:

```
|                 stdt |
|----------------------|
| 1-Rohit-One-AJan     |
| 2-Karuna-Two-Jan,Feb |
```

Comment: Thanks but I think you don't understand my expected output. Adding `std_fee.f_tm IS NUll` in `ON` clause, I get following result - `1-Rohit-One-A,2-Karuna-Two-`, Here all fee month are missing, I need `1-Rohit-One-A-Feb,2-Karuna-Two-Jan, Feb`. So I tried replacing `OR` instead of `AND` in your answer. And I am close to my expectation. `1-Rohit-One-Jan,2-Karuna-Two-Feb,2-Karuna-Two-Jan` but still can't get exact result. [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d28199/36)

Comment: @Dipak You need to use a `group by` clause for student id

Comment: @Dipak No problem glad to help :)